# Python - Prime finder/calculator error

Tags: python

Okay, I know my code is extremely inefficient and longer than it be, but I am very new to python and only know a few basic functions.

```
restart = True
numtocheck = 2 #number to be tested for being a prime
while 0==0: #forever loop
    if restart == True: 
        testnum = 2 #used to test the 'numtocheck' varible
    calculated = numtocheck/testnum
    if (calculated).is_integer():
       numtocheck = numtocheck+1
    else:
        testnum = testnum+1
        if numtocheck == testnum:
            print (numtocheck) #Should be a prime
            numtocheck = numtocheck+1
            restart = True
        else:
            restart = False
```

The output is almost perfectly full of primes, however there are several which appear such as '35' or '95' which keep appearing every time I run the code. I have no idea what is happening, and so any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Side note: despite of you being new to Python as you say, you seem to be aware of the constant expression `True`, so why on earth are you doing `while 0==0` instead of `while True`?

Comment: What is `is_integer`?

Comment: Front note: `numtocheck/testnum` always yields an integer, so `calculated` is **always** an integer. To begin with, change it to `float(numtocheck)/testnum`.

Comment: Use the remainder operator (%). If remainder = 0, the dividend is divisible by the divisor.

Comment: How many primes are you trying to calculate? / What exactly are you trying to do? You don't explicitly say what that is.

Comment: @barakmanos That's not true in Python 3

Comment: @barakmanos I didn't use 'while True' because I didn't know it would work in a loop, so thanks for the advise! Also, as mentioned by Kolmar, python 3 automatically selected the correct type of variable based on what it's told to store so I'm guessing you use python 2?

Comment: @figs The is_integer function will return a boolean True or False if the variable is an integer. For example, if x=1.2 then '(x).is_integer()' would return False

Comment: @Malonge To use the % operator, would x%y give the remainder of x/y? Eg. 3%2 = 0.5? Also, it was supposed to be a very simple program that calculated and printed prime numbers. It wasn't supposed to have an end to the program because I was trying to keep it as simple as possible. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add some debug output and try to analyze what happens.
First of all it is obviously python 3, because python 2 won't execute this code. Ok.
I'll add some debug output to your code like this:

```
restart = True
numtocheck = 2 #number to be tested for being a prime
i = 0
while i<150: #not forever loop now :)
    if restart == True: 
        testnum = 2 #used to test the 'numtocheck' varible
    calculated = numtocheck/testnum
    if (calculated).is_integer():
       numtocheck = numtocheck+1
    else:
        testnum = testnum+1
        if numtocheck == testnum:
            print (numtocheck) #Should be a prime
            numtocheck = numtocheck+1
            restart = True
        else:
            restart = False
    print ('numtocheck %s'%numtocheck)
    print ('testnum %s'%testnum)
    i+=1
```

Ok, here is result (i took number 27 as a good example):

```
numtocheck 26
testnum 13
numtocheck 27
testnum 13
numtocheck 27
testnum 14
numtocheck 27
```

So here we are. You are checking number 26. 26/12 is float, ok, you increase testnum to 13 and 26/13 is int. Hurray. You go to next numtocheck - 27. But forget to clear testnum var and it is still 13. So you start from testing 27/13, then 27/14 and so on until 27 and as a result - 27 is a prime, because you've lost 27/3 and 27/9. 
So add

```
testnum = 2
```

after

```
if (calculated == 0):
       numtocheck = numtocheck+1
```

and everything will be ok.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Helped me a lot and now works with a little bit of tweaking. :D

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably the following:

```
restart = True
numtocheck = 2 #number to be tested for being a prime
while 0==0: #forever loop
    if restart == True: 
        testnum = 2 #used to test the 'numtocheck' varible
    calculated = numtocheck % testnum    #modulo computation
    if (calculated == 0):
       numtocheck = numtocheck+1
    else:
        testnum = testnum+1
        if numtocheck == testnum:
            print (numtocheck) #Should be a prime
            numtocheck = numtocheck+1
            restart = True
        else:
            restart = False
```

Hope this helps... the algorithm is probably not exactly what you expect, but this is another subject.

Comment: I think I now understand the '%' operator a bit more and also doesn't require the 'is_integer' bit either. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems like you want to just print every prime number? Since this is just going on forever, these numbers will get big. Accordingly, I add a break statement to move onto the next integer at the instance the current integer is deemed non prime. Something like this:

```
i = 3
while True:
    is_prime = True
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i%j == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break

    if is_prime == True:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

Comment: I'm afraid because I am inexperienced in python, I don't quite understand 'for' loops and have no idea how to use use breaks :/ But thanks for the advise anyway :)